# How to clone local svn work directory to git repo and upload to github?

Tags: git, github, svn, clone

The task is to migrate from local svn work directory to git repository and upload to remote github.

> System: Windows 10 64  bit
>
> git-svn version: 2.21.0.windows.1 (svn 1.9.7)

1- I installed **TortoiseGit** and try to apply git clone command and provide the origin to point to the github url using

> username:tokem@github.company.com/repo.git

I got this error: "Using existing [svn-remote "svn"]
svn-remote.svn.fetch already set to track :refs/remotes/git-svn"

2- Using GitBatch I run:

```
svn log -q svnurl | grep '^r[0-9]' | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq > authors.txt
```

I got the authors.txt correctly
then I run:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

and

```
git svn clone file:///C/Users/Documents/GitHub/Repo --authors-file=C://authors.txt C://Users//Documents/GitHub/Repo_Git
```

I got the same error:
git-svn windows Using existing [svn-remote "svn"]
svn-remote.svn.fetch already set to track :refs/remotes/git-svn

Till now I couldn't clone local svn to git and then to upload to github, please help

I read git-svn documentation and read svn2git tool guide but don't help!

Thanks in advance,
Mariam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-svn` is better suited if you're going to push/pull commits between git and svn. For a straight export, `svn2git` is a much better solution and way faster.
https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, how can I install svn2git on windows!

Comment: Windows 10? You could install Windows Subsystem for Linux.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10. Otherwise there is another svn2git product. I haven't used this one tho... https://chriskirby.net/blog/migrate-an-existing-repository-from-subversion-to-git-on-windows-with-history-intact

Comment: Will try this if it works this will be my answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

GitHub recommends a few tools in their [Source code migration tools](https://help.github.com/en/articles/source-code-migration-tools) help page.

Warning: there are several "svn2git" tools:

- The one recommended on this GitHub help page is implemented in Ruby.
- The one in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55475018/6352677 is implemented in C++.